# How do I turn all of these faces into just one?

Tags: faces, edges, subdivision-surface

[image]

I had to subdivide a face multiple times so that I could make the holes you see in the image. I no longer wish to have the face subdivided and I wish instead to turn all of these faces into just one. How do I do it?

Also, if you know of a better way to make holes in a face, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: X > Limited Dissolve?

Answer (score 2):

Create a single big face of the whole wall. Then use the edge function "Loop cut and slide": press Ctrl R, move the mouse to choose its orientation, click one time to confirm, move the mouse to choose the correct location, click again to confirm.

After the first click you can scroll the mouse wheel to create more loops.

Repeat as needed.

At the end of the procedure you can dissolve the remaining edges, if you need to.

[image]